# C++ Builder X3 Synchronize error

Tags: c++, builder

T've been struggling with this all afternoon.
My thread class is:

```
class TLoadingThread : public TThread
{
    protected:
        virtual void __fastcall Execute();
        void Spin(); //to be synchronized

    public:
        __fastcall TLoadingThread();
          void __fastcall GentleStop();
        long m_Stop;
};
```

My Execute method:

```
void __fastcall TLoadingThread::Execute()
{
    while (!m_Stop)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        Synchronize(&Spin);
    }

    m_Stop = 0;
}
```

causes compiler error:

```
[bcc32 Error] WaitInfoWindow.cpp(59): E2285 Could not find a match for 'TThread::Synchronize(void (* (_closure )())())'
  Full parser context
    WaitInfoWindow.cpp(55): parsing: void _fastcall TLoadingThread::Execute()
```

also

```
Synchronize(Spin);
```

causes

```
[bcc32 Error] WaitInfoWindow.cpp(59): E2285 Could not find a match for 'TThread::Synchronize(void)'
  Full parser context
    WaitInfoWindow.cpp(55): parsing: void _fastcall TLoadingThread::Execute()
```

I read for some only Synchronize(&Spin); works, for others both
Synchronize(Spin); and Synchronize(&Spin); work too but with my none of these work.
I'm using:

X3 C++ Builder Update1.
Maybe it's something with compiler settings I should change?

best regards

Tomasz

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not familiar with C++ Builder. It seems to have some incompatibilities/extensions to C++.

---

The documentation for [`TThread.Synchronize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) shows two appropriate methods for your call:

```
void __fastcall Synchronize(TThreadMethod AMethod)/* overload */;
void __fastcall Synchronize(_di_TThreadProcedure AThreadProc)/* overload */;
```

---

The first error message hints at a pointer to a [`__closure`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Closure). In C++, to pass the address of a *method*, you would rather say

```
Synchronize(&TLoadingThread::Spin);
```

although, I can't tell, if this is valid in C++ Builder.

---

For the second error message, maybe it is interpreted as a *call* to `Spin` resulting in `void`. And, of course, there is no `TThread::Synchronize(void)` as per documentation. But this is just a guess.

---

The different reports of `Synchronize(Spin)` working for some and `Synchronize(&Spin)` working for others, might be for the second overload of `Synchronize`, which seems to take a pointer to a function. Passing a pointer to a function can be either by a plain

```
Synchronize(function_name);
```

or by prefixing with an `&`

```
Synchronize(&function_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately

```
Synchronize(&TLoadingThread::Spin);
```

yelds:

```
[bcc32 Error] WaitInfoWindow.cpp(71): E2285 Could not find a match for 'TThread::Synchronize(void (TLoadingThread::*)())'
  Full parser context
    WaitInfoWindow.cpp(67): parsing: void _fastcall TLoadingThread::Execute()
```

I'm completely helpless, each example I've found shows that I made no mistake but the compiler keeps reporting error.
This drives me mad :/